# Python format print to evenly print numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, format

I have an array of integers I'm trying to evenly print out, say the data set is

`7 14 23 49 191`

I'm looping through this array, `content` with

```
for num in content:
    print(num,"",end="")
```

now I need to place a `|` above certain elements in my list( for a box plot generation via console ). How can I know where to place the `|` symbol when some integers may take up additional space? I tried

```
#print | above certain numbers
for num in content:
    if num == theone:
        print("|",end="")
    else:
        print(" ",end="")

#print numbers as before
for num in content:
    print(num,"",end="")
```

but this will give me

```
  |  | 
7 14 23 49 191
```

as opposed to

```
   |     |
7 14 23 49 191
```

because the integers below are not just one digit. Is there an easy way to get past this? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
content = [7, 14, 23, 49, 191,]
ticks = [0,1,0,1,0]

fmt = '{:>5}'

for tic in ticks:
    print(fmt.format('|' if tic else""), end="")
print()
for num in content:
    print(fmt.format(num) ,end="")
print()
```

**EDIT:** To produce the exact format, according to Ashwini Chaudhary's comment, try this way:

```
content = [7, 14, 23, 49, 191]
widths = [' '*len(str(c)) for c in content]
the_ones = [False, True, False, True, False] # or any other way to
                                             # signal which ones to tick
for i, t in enumerate(the_ones):
    if t == True:
        widths[i] = widths[i][:-1]+'|'

print(' '.join(widths))
print(' '.join(map(str, content)))
```

Comment: This will add a bunch of spaces at the start, and that's not what OP wants.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary See edit to produce the exact format. Excuse my not knowing, what is OP?

Comment: OP means Original Poster, your code seems to be working fine now. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
lst = [7, 14, 23, 49, 191]

for x in lst:
    n = len(str(x))
    if x in (14, 49): #some condition
        # if we want to print the | at the end of the number then we first need
        # to add (n-1) spaces before it and then add a |. Lastly end with a ' '
        # so that the cursor moves to the start of next number.
        print (' ' * (n-1) + '|', end=' ')
    else:
        # simply print n space so that cursor moves to the end of the number
        # and end it with a ' ' to move the cursor to the start of next number
        print (' ' * n, end=' ')

print()

for x in lst:
    print (x, end=' ')
```

**Output:**

```
   |     |     
7 14 23 49 191
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a fixed width representations of the numbers:

```
# Sample data
content = [1, 10, 100, 1000]

# Will be 4, since 1000 has four digits
max_digits = max(len(str(n)) for n in content)

# '<4' will be left-aligned; switch to > for right-aligned
fmt_string = '<{}'.format(max_digits)

# Print out the digits
for n in content:
    s = format(n, fmt_string)
    # Do your thing to determine whether to place a bar
    print(s, end='')
```

See [more](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) on string formatting.

Comment: Note that OP is printing those pipes on the last digits not the first ones.

Answer (score 0):

```
from math import floor,ceil
numbers = [7, 14, 23, 49, 191]
selection = [14, 49]
indexes = sorted([numbers.index(n) for n in selection])

def selectors():
    string = ""
    for n in xrange(len(numbers)):
        len_number = len(str(numbers[n]))
        if len_number == 1:
            pad = "|"
        elif len_number == 2:
            pad = " |"
        else:
            pad = " " * (int(ceil(len_number / 2.0)-1)) + "|" + " " * (int(floor(len_number / 2.0)))
        if n not in indexes:
            pad = pad.replace("|", " ")
        string += pad+" "
    return string

print (selectors())
print (" ".join([str(n) for n in numbers]))
```

Output:

```
   |     |     
7 14 23 49 191
```

This one is pretty simple actually,

It will add the pipe("|") to every character in the string, right in the middle, if the number is not in the selection it replaces the pipe character with a space.

Other example

```
numbers = [0,100,1000,10000,100000, 1000000, 10000000]
selection = [1000, 100000, 10000000]

       |           |               |     
0 100 1000 10000 100000 1000000 10000000
```